# Appium, webdriver.io, Runner in test suite only shows one test despite beeing multiple

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, appium, webdriver-io

I'm trying to create a test suite with multiple test cases. When I add 2 test cases in the suite and run them, in runner I see that the total count is 1 of 1 instead of 2.
[Image of the runner.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEsuM.png)

I'm using appium with webdriver.io and mocha, where is my mistake?
thanks!

```
describe('News tests', () => {
  it('Creation of news', async () => {
    var newstab = await $('~NewsTab');
    await newstab.waitForDisplayed({timeout: 30000} ); 
    await newstab.click();
    var createnewbtn = await $('~create news button');
    await createnewbtn.waitForDisplayed({timeout: 30000} );   
    await createnewbtn.click();
    var HeadlineField = await $('~headline input');
    await HeadlineField.waitForDisplayed({timeout: 30000} );   
    await HeadlineField.addValue('Automated Test'); 
    var DeskField = await $('~description input');    
    await DeskField.waitForDisplayed({timeout: 30000} );   
    await DeskField.addValue('Automated Test description'); 
    var closebtn = await $('~close button');
    await closebtn.waitForDisplayed({timeout: 30000} );   
    await closebtn.click();
 });
  it('Create new and cancel', async () => {
    var newstab = await $('~NewsTab');
    await newstab.waitForDisplayed({timeout: 30000} ); 
    await newstab.click();
    var createnewbtn = await $('~create news button');
    await createnewbtn.waitForDisplayed({timeout: 30000} );   
    await createnewbtn.click();
    var closebtn = await $('~close button');
    await closebtn.waitForDisplayed({timeout: 30000} );   
    await closebtn.click();
  });
});
```

Comment: There is an extra `})` after the first test block. did you try removing it?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my code with the latest that I use, but I'm still seeing only one test case in runner

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, apparently, I was using the default test runner which didn't show the steps of the tests, new runner fixed the issue